# GetIdleTime() in Windows CE/WM does not work?

Tags: windows-ce, windows-mobile-6

I am trying to get the device IdleTime by calling GetIdleTime()

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
static extern int GetIdleTime();
```

but idle time keeps incrementing even when the device is not idle.

I call the function with a button click and everytime I click the button the time has incremented even when I do it repeatedly. Why does the time increase when it it not idle?  Is there a better better approach to get the device idle time?

Comment: OK i found the answer here http://www.iamraf.net/Samples/User-activity-detection-on-the-Compact-Framework